# Error in configuration scope "default config" in General>Web

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

When going to *Default Config > Web* I get the following error.

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> ```
> Invalid config field backend model: adminhtml/system_config_backend_web_secure_offloaderheader
> Trace:
> #0 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid config ...')
> #1 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
> #2 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
> #3 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm()
> #4 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm()
> #5 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction()
> #6 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
> #7 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #8 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #9 /home/wengkomole/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #10 /home/wengkomole/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #11 {main}
> ```

On the other hand when selecting current configuration scope (Main Website) I don't get the error.

Comment: seems like `{magento-root}/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Web/Secure/Offloaderheader.php` file is missing

Comment: Thank you, but the above file does not exist in the Magento Version 1.9.0.1. Maybe another files is missing but I can not find which one.

Comment: MeenakshiSundaram R, You were right. That file was missing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment

> {magento-root}/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Web/Sec‌​ure/Offloaderheader.php

Above file is missing in your magento, so please copy the file from fresh magento and paste it in your system.